Is there a way to check each row in a sheet until the formula returns true?
Problem: Go through a list in Sheet1 (starting from top to bottom) and check if that value is repeated more than once in Sheet2. If the value is repeated more than once in Sheet2 then return that value, if the value is not repeated more than once in Sheet2, check the second value on the list in Sheet1 (then check value 3, and so on).
I've tried using countif functions but the problem I'm running into is that the value I'm looking for needs to change if the equation returns as FALSE.
e.x
Sheet1

Dog
Cat
Fish
...

Sheet2

Dog
Cat
Cat
Fish
Cat
Fish


(check cell A2) - Dog
COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A2)>1 = FALSE -> No value returned, check next on the list
(check cell A3) - Cat
COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A3)>1 = TRUE -> Value returned = Cat

The equation stops here since the formula has returned TRUE.
Since cell A2 would return false, the equation would then have to move onto checking if cell A3 is repeated in Sheet2 but I don't know how I would be able to do this.
As of right now I've brute forced my way through it by using a IFS function and typing out all the steps to go through since I will only have 30 values in the list. But because of this it has also made my equation extremely large.
I know that this can probably be solved using some other method but I have no idea how to use or operate them. I am open to trying different things out but I would prefer to have an equation to solve my issue.
This is my first time posting so sorry if I confused you or if the question was misleading.
Thanks in advance.

You could find all the values in the first range that appear more than once in the second range with:
=FILTER(A:A,1<COUNTIF(B:B,A:A))


and then only return the first one:
=+FILTER(A:A,1<COUNTIF(B:B,A:A))



Thanks so much for your response. This solution worked perfectly for me. I had no idea that you could grab the first result in a filter by adding a plus in front. Is there any other tricks similar to that or a place where I can find those shortcuts?

this only works if the formula is not array enabled so I don't recommend relying too much on it. For simple problems like this it's fine but in general it's safer to use INDEX(array,1,1).

A good way to do an analysis with a single result from looping values is to use REDUCE. What I stated is that if the value keeps being FALSE, then tries counting next one, or if not it keeps the first value that meets the criteria.
    =REDUCE(FALSE,TOCOL(Sheet2!A2:A,1),LAMBDA(a,v,
IF(a=FALSE,IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,v)>1,v,FALSE),
a)))


This looks pretty interesting to me although a bit too complicated for me to understand right now. Thanks for the response though and I'll definitely look deeper into this so I can use it in the future!
